# Need to open a PDF document through oracle forms 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am using oracle 10 g. I have a PDF file located in a folder in server. I want to open that PDF by a hyperlink.

I am accessing server using URL

```
http://ipaddress:port/forms/frmservlet?form=YYYY/forms/login.fmx
```

Inside this form folder I have a PDF file

I want to open that PDF file while running Oracle forms

I created a button and on click I wrote

```
declare
   str_url varchar2(500);
begin
   Str_URL:= :global.apath||'/form/a.pdf';
   WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT(Str_URL, '_BLANK');        
end;
```

Here global.path has my server location. However, the PDF is not opening. Please help.

Comment: Does the PDF open if you copy/paste the `STR_URL` into the browser's address bar?

Comment: No it is not opening

Comment: Then you can't expect Forms to do that either. I think (and I think that I'm right) that directory **on the IAS** - which contains those files - should be somehow "exposed" and thus accessible from the *outside*. I've never done that, but I've heard that setting up the IAS isn't a trivial task. If you already have it up and running, that's a huge advantage. I'd say that setting up "privileges" (or whatever it is called) so that you'd be able to access files in that directory should be an easy task for someone who knows what to do. I, unfortunately, don't. Ask your administrator.